# Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Function "SYSUTCDATETIME" not found; SQL statement:[90022-200]

Tags: java, sql, repository, h2, junit5

I am testing the repository class with insert query and facing issue:

ERROR:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Function "SYSUTCDATETIME" not found; SQL statement:
insert into table name (cloumns1..x) values (?, ?, ?, SYSUTCDATETIME(), ?, ? , ?, SYSUTCDATETIME(),?); [90022-200]
```

VERSION:

I am using unit juniper version 5.8.x

Expectation
Can someone please help

Answer (score 0):

In h2 there is no `SYSUTCDATETIME()` this function exists in SQL Server, for h2 you have to use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, for example:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (cloumns1, .., x) 
values (?, ?, ?, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, ?, ? , ?, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, ?);
```